# Each character replace from string in python

Tags: python, string, replace

I am new in programming...My code is very simple. Let's say my number is '123' then i want to get 'abc' .please check where i am wrong

```
def number2char(number):
    search_array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]
    replace_array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
    num_2_char = number.replace(search_array, replace_array);
    return num_2_char;
```

I am getting an error here like this

> num_2_char = number.replace(search_array, replace_array);
>   TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Please help me...

Comment: You can't just guess at what you want a method to do. It does what it was documented to do. For [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), what it does is replace one substring with another substring.

Comment: Thanks for editing...please anyone help me!

Comment: Is it intentional that you have `"d"` twice in a row?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) replaces one substring with a replacement substring. That's what the error means: it wants a substring, and you gave it a list of separate characters.

---

You could loop over the replacement pairs, calling `replace` for each one:

```
>>> s = '123'
>>> for search, replace in zip(search_array, replace_array):
...     s = s.replace(search, replace)
>>> s
'abc'
```

---

Or you could just use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), which actually *does* do what you want, although it requires a bit of setup:

```
>>> search_array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]
>>> replace_array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
>>> trans = str.maketrans(dict(zip(search_array, replace_array)))
>>> '123'.translate(trans)
'abc'
```

Or, alternatively, and probably more readable:

```
>>> search = "1234567890"
>>> replace = "abcddefghi"
>>> trans = str.maketrans(search, replace)
>>> '123'.translate(trans)
'abc'
```

---

By the way, if it isn't intentional that you specified `d` twice in a row, it might be clearer (and harder to make that typo!) to specify the letters like this:

```
>>> replace = string.ascii_lowercase[:10]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary instead. There's a few steps here:

1. We want to map every number to a character, so we can create a dictionary with the input characters as keys and the output characters as values.
2. You can't iterate a numerical input, so we have to convert it to a string to access each character in turn. In your example the value is already a string (`'123'`) but there's no reason you can't make the function accept both numerical and string inputs.
3. The replacement is done in a list comprehension, which naturally returns a list. So you need to call `join()` to join all of the characters back together into a single string.

One approach is as follows:

```
def number2char(number):
    search_array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]
    replace_array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
    replace_dict = dict(zip(search_array, replace_array))
    num_2_char = ''.join([replace_dict.get(char, '_') 
                          for char in str(number)])
    return num_2_char

a = number2char(123)
```

In this case I've used `replace_dict.get(str(item), '_')` so that the code doesn't crash if someone gives an input that isn't in the `replace_dict`; instead they just get back underscores. There's probably better ways to handle that, but it's safer than just trying to access the dictionary as `replace_dict[item]`.

Comment: Great explanation and very helpful . Thank you very much @roganjosh

Comment: What is point 2 about? The OP says the input is `123'`, which is a string. Plus, if it _weren't_ a string, he wouldn't get the `TypeError`  he got, he'd get an `AttributeError`.

Comment: @abarnert ah, that's a fair enough observation. You're right, I missed that the input was already a string, but I was already working on an explanation for `dict.get()`. I guess that point is a bit redundant but I'm not sure it affects the flow of the explanation to be removed?

Comment: I think it confuses things, especially for a novice who's going to start trying to figure out why `'123'` isn't a string.

Comment: Also, I think `dict.get(item, item)` might be more useful than `dict.get(item, '_')`… but that's really up to what the OP wants to happen in that case. (He might actually want an error, because that's a "this should never happen" case, for all I know.)

Comment: @abarnert for the second comment, I think my explanation is reasonable. The OP didn't say what they expected in that case, I just gave an example of how one might go about handling something they may not have even considered. But I will have a think how to coherently change (2) to fit with the narrative I had in my head.

Comment: While we're at it, even if point 2 were a problem here, you don't need `str(item)`; the elements of a string are strings. (It might be worth renaming it to `char` or something to make that clearer? Not sure about that part…)

Comment: @roganjosh you can use `join` using generator expression, e.g. `''.join(replace_dict.get(str(item), '_') for item in str(number))`. This will not produce unnecessary list object

Comment: With the edit, point 2 is no longer misleading, but I still think it's useless. You've just invented a new problem that the OP doesn't have, and that nobody searching for this question in the future is likely to have, just so you can solve it. There's enough to explain without doing that.

Comment: @EirNym no, you should not use a generator in `join()`. The list will be created regardless before `join` can go about actually building the string.

Comment: @roganjosh please explain, it works fine for me in both Python 2 and Python 3

Comment: @EirNym At least as of CPython 3.7, `join` is just going to create a list if you pass it a generator expression. It will be slightly slower that way, and use the same amount of memory. I still think it's sometimes worth using generator expressions with `join` for clarity—because the fact that it's a list is really just a micro-optimization, not something meaningful—but you definitely shouldn't go doing it every time, and especially not because you mistakenly think you're saving memory.

Comment: @EirNym I'm not saying that it won't work. What I'm saying is that the entire list will be created beforehand, so it ends up being less efficient than using a list comp in the first place.

Comment: it doesn't or I don't see the line where it does. Please, show me if I'm wrong https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Objects/stringlib/join.h

Comment: @EirNym Do you not see that `seq = PySequence_Fast`, or do you not know [what that function does](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/sequence.html#c.PySequence_Fast)? (Also, you're looking at `bytes.join`, not `str.join`, but [that does the same thing](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L9870).)

Comment: Thanks, I've missed this line

Comment: @EirNym There was a proposal to change this a few years back—but it turns out that the speed gain from being able to `PySequence_Fast_ITEMS` and then loop directly over the array actually outweighs the cost of the `PySequence_Fast` unless your iterables are really tiny (in which case it doesn't matter) or so big that the memory allocation starts to dominate (in which case you're usually not joining that many strings, or at least shouldn't be—e.g., you should be writing those 15M lines with `writelines` rather than `write(join(…))`).

Answer (score -1):

```
def number2char(number):
    search_array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]
    replace_array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
    num_2_char=''
    for i in number:
        num_2_char +=  replace_array[search_array.index(i)]
    return num_2_char;
```

Comment: This really isn't a good solution. Almost any time you find yourself calling `index` on a list, it's a sign that you're using either the wrong data structure or the wrong algorithm. Here, you could just use a dict, instead of linearly searching through every character every time—it would be simpler, and clearer in meaning, and even more efficient (not that it's going to matter here). But at that point, you've just got roganjosh's answer.